# What are the appropriate smoothness conditions that will ensure a maximum likelihood estimator is consistent?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

According to a theorem, under appropriate smoothness conditions on $f$ , the maximum likelihood estimator from an i.i.d. sample is consistent. So what are the conditions that will ensure that the estimators are consistent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is some places the conditions are not specified clearly.
One set of sufficien requisites are Wald constrains:

1. Different models have different parameter values
2. The set of parameter allowable values is compact
3. The likelihood function is continuous.
4. The set of probable samples
   (with density>0) does not depends on the parameter value.

see   [this link about the subject](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~lebanon/notes/mleConsistency.pdf)